# Transient filesystem key/value store from Ruby on Heroku?

Tags: database, heroku

I need to run a process that deals with a large volume of data. Too large to reasonably work with in RAM. The data does not need to be preserved between process instances or shared between process instances though, so I was hoping to use some kind of disk-based database for the storage.

My first thought was SQLite, but Heroku explicitly does not support that. Te second thing that I tried was Ruby's `PStore`, but that turned out to be way too flakey for the job. The next thing that I tried was DBM, which Heroku does not seem to say that they don't support. When I tried to run the code after deploying it, however, I got "LoadError: cannot load such file -- dbm".

Given that I do *not* need data to be persisted between process instances, is there any way to work around Heroku's bias against support for file-based relational or key/value data stores?

Comment: My temporary solution is to use https://github.com/peterc/rsmaz to cram data into RAM, but that is WAAAAY slower than the solution using DBM that won't run on Heroku, and if the data set grows much larger than it is now, I could still end up thrashing memory, which could make it unusably slow.

Comment: I ended up trying SDBM, but it proved to be too flaky. I never did find a workable tool, but I wrote a custom file-based solution for the problem, which worked better and faster than compressing the data to squeeze it into RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the structure of the data is, but have you considered using Redis? There is an effective free tier on Heroku. The issue with file based solutions are that Heroku uses an ephemeral file system. It's not designed to scale disk space among computing units.

Comment: Redis was actually the first thing I tried, but the free tier is way too small. I have about 10x more room Dyno RAM than in Redis, so it actually makes the problem worse rather than better. It would cost about $40/mo for enough Redis storage to be helpful.